# Is it possible to return raw object from generic method?

Tags: java, generics, collections, generic-method

research this method from `Colletions` class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static final <T> Set<T> emptySet() {
        return (Set<T>) EMPTY_SET;
    }
```

---

```
Collections.emptySet() return `Set<Object>`
```

This behaviour differ from generic classes. If I instantiate generic class without `<T>` I work with raw object.

I noticed this after method accept generic set was failed as compilation error:

```
public class GenericMethodRaw {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Set set = Collections.emptySet();
        method(set); //fine
        method(Collections.emptySet());  //compilation error here
        Set<String> set1 = Collections.emptySet();//fine compilation
    }
    public static void method(Set<String> strings){}
}
```

compiler message:

```
java: method method in class GenericMethodRaw cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.Set<java.lang.String>
  found: java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>
  reason: actual argument java.util.Set<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<java.lang.String> by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: Your last sentence makes no sense to me, would you mind rephrasing? Also; I see a question in the title, but none in the actual question text. Normally the title should summarize the question, and you should include a question in the body. Altough that might just be me..

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem you mention is a compilation error because the result of a method like "Collections.emptySet" was not usable in a method that accepts a raw collection?

Could you provide an example?

Comment: My method argument has type Set<String> . I expected that method return raw type and this value will acceptable for my method

Comment: @gstackoverflow you should do `yourMethod(Collections.<String>emptySet())`

Comment: Yes. I understood. I just want to investigate theory.

Comment: Your sample compiles in Java 8 which has better type inference.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis thanks, interesting fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology wise, an object isn't `raw`. The type of a reference value can be. The type of the value returned by a method must be compatible with the method's return type. In the `emptySet` method it is because of the cast.

In any case, the client will never see what happens in the call, all they know is that the method invocation expression has a type based on its invocation context.

Comment: Types are [raw](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: Can I supress type evaluation in generic method?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: I have generic class. For example ArrayList. If I create it 
follows ArrayList a = new ArrayList() -  I can work as with raw type. At this case I can forgot about generic.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Within the generic method, you cannot suppress the method's generic type parameter, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to create a set with raw object, consider creating it with wildcard.

```
Set<?> set = Collections.emptySet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in concrete example:

`Collections` class has public field for this:

```
Collections.EMPTY_SET
```

In general looks like you cannot use raw version of generic method. Compiler would try evaluate type anyway.